# flexislider..slide image disappears with width reduced to below 770

Tags: flexslider

on the home page the slides are visible but till the width of the screen is reduced to around mobile size at which point the slides disappear.

I tired everything I could think of played with .flexslider .slides img ...

currently i have it set as `.flexslider .slides img {width: auto; height: auto;display: block; max-width: 100%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}`

thanx in advance

**issue resolved i had another code which was intercepting this ...changing that solved the issue**

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: modified the post above with what i have currently

Comment: No slider on that site.

Comment: plz recheck ..its there on homepage